# If user does not select/capture image I get null pointer on upload?

Tags: upload, photo

I have searched everywhere. I have an app that user can enter details and if required take a photo. This works uploading it to SQL and the image to a server folder. (I am using volley and reduce the file size)

The problem is that if the user does not take a photo then when the click the upload/insert button I get a toast stating

---

### *NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference*

I have been trying to work out code to programmatically load a default image on create so that this can be used if the user decides not to add a picture . If the user takes a photo then this is ok since it already works.
I have also tried using an if statement to use a default drawable but this doesn't work? Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
The code is extensive so just copied the image related stuff.

I am thinking it may either be the php server script or the java class in the app. I have been focusing on the method getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) below as it appears this is where the nullobject is referenced if a user does not decide to take a picture

```js
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      ImageView imageViewPic;
      private Bitmap bmp;
      private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
      String image_path, insertUrl = "http://www.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/upload.php";

      @
      Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          imageViewPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Pic);

          buttonCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
            Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              image_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/tmp_image.jpg";
              File img = new File(image_path);
              Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(img);

              Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
              intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
              startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
          });


          insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
            Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
              imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
              radioRiskGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadiogrp);
              int selectedId = radioRiskGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
              radioRiskButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
              final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
              StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl,
                new Response.Listener < String > () {

                  @
                  Override
                  public void onResponse(String response) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {@
                  Override
                  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                }) {

                protected Map < String, String > getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                  Map < String, String > parameters = new HashMap < String, String > ();
                  parameters.put("Date", Mysqldateformat.getText().toString());
                  parameters.put("Time", Mysqltimeformat.getText().toString());
                  parameters.put("Name", name.getText().toString());
                  parameters.put("Email", email.getText().toString());
                  parameters.put("Telephone", telephone.getText().toString());

                  parameters.put("image", getStringImage(bmp));
                  return parameters;
                }
              };
              RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
              requestQueue.add(request);
            }
          });
        }
        //end OnCreateBundle

      @
      Override
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
          imageViewPic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
          imageViewPic.invalidate();

        }
      }

      //**************
      public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
      }
    }
     //end
```